# security concerns in form's console log

Tags: security

I would appreciate any advice here. While using a form (containing PII) I noticed this system was logging keystrokes to the console log. Here is an example form on their website:

https://www.formdesk.com/demo/marathon.payment2?payment=test

Open up the console and hammer a few keystrokes.

Question is: is this a security threat worth addressing? I reached out to the company, but they weren't particularly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt this is a security concern, but it does sound like they were sloppy enough to leave debugging code in release build.

Comment: Yeah that's what i was thinking too. At best sloppy. Thanks.